# How to change the background of a styled.div if the window is scrolled to the top?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I would like to change the background of a div if the window is scrolled to the top. I have figured out how to determine that in React, and when console.logging my `isAtTop` variable it will change based on the scroll, however the actual div never seems to receive as the styled.div doesn't change colors. I have made a codePen: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-chebyshev-4poi3?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import React from 'react'

import styled from 'styled-components'

export default function App() {
  let isAtTop = true;
  let bg = `linear-gradient(to right, #797cd2, #393e9e)`;

  function handleScroll() {
    isAtTop = window.scrollY === 0;

    isAtTop
      ? (bg = `linear-gradient(to right, #797cd2, #393e9e)`)
      : (bg = "white");
    console.log({ isAtTop });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect Run");
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });

  const ColorChangeDiv = styled.div`
  background: ${bg};
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  `

  return (
    <>
    <ColorChangeDiv>
    {isAtTop.toString()} ? Hello my background should be {bg}
    </ColorChangeDiv>
    <div style={{height: '500rem'}}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little, now I will explain what exactly changed.

1. Made the functions arrow, so it looks cleaner
2. Wrapped the scroll event handler in useCallback to exclude unnecessary calls to useEffect, since now this function is in useEffect dependencies and it is a good practice to specify all dependencies used in useEffect.
3. The background color is now stored in the state. You were storing in a variable, the component is not re-rendered on changing the let variable. This means that even changing the value of the variable, the component will not display itself with the new values. We need a rerender. A change in state causes a rerender. This means that if you want to change the component depending on the changed values, then store them in a state to call the rerender :)
4. I brought the styled component out, it looks cleaner and plus, it makes no sense to keep it inside the APP component, you can pass the values ​​to the styled component in props. Check out the example below, now the background is passed as props
5. You have long default background values. And it repeats itself. Such long repetitive things are better to be translated into constants with good understandable names. See I brought it up as DEFAULT_BG.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-pasteur-18v0r?file=/src/App.js:361-372

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const DEFAULT_BG = `linear-gradient(to right, #797cd2, #393e9e)`;

const ColorChangeDiv = styled.div`
  background: ${(p) => p.bg};
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 2000px;
`;

const App = () => {
  const [bg, setBg] = useState(DEFAULT_BG);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    setBg(window.scrollY === 0 ? DEFAULT_BG : "white");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [handleScroll]);

  return (
    <>
      <ColorChangeDiv bg={bg}>
        Hello my background should be {bg}
      </ColorChangeDiv>
      <div style={{ height: "500rem" }}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```